# IIS 7.5, internal network/router, single SSL; google pointing to non-SSL sites

Tags: ssl, iis, google

The situation is that I have a few web sites on a home-hosted server. Of these, just one has SSL set up. Of course, with IIS and a single IP home network, you can only have one SSL site. That's fine. However, for some reason, Google has indexed some of the domain names with https, and when it does that, the server serves up the only valid HTTPS web site even though the domain / host header does not match. And, of course, if you visit those sites, you get a security warning for the same reason. So my question is two parts:

1. How do I keep Google from indexing these sites incorrectly?
2. How can I forward users that hit the HTTPS sites to the correct domain? (Likely has to be done on each of those sites, but maybe there's an IIS server setting?)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your questions, but the better solution would be to upgrade to a later version of IIS (Windows 2012 or above), at which point you can enable SNI in the bindings and have SSL on all sites using a single IP, differentiated with host headers.